# Python:- How to create Csv from Excel(for specific columns)

Tags: python, excel, csv

I want to Create Csv from Excel but only with two specific  columns.

```
csv_file = open(csv_file_path, 'w+')
wr = csv.writer(csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

for row_num in xrange(sh.nrows):
  wr.writerow(sh.row_values(row_num))
```

This Script is Writing all rows of sh sheet into Csv file, i want to write only specific columns into my csv with Header "Id" and "Price" .??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the indeces you can do it this way:

```
import xlrd

wb = xlrd.open_workbook("myfile.xlsx")
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

headers = ['Price', 'Id']
headers_index = []

for index,column in enumerate(sh.row_values(0)):
    if column in headers:
        if column in headers:
            headers_index.append(index)


for row_num in range(sh.nrows):
    output = [sh.row_values(row_num)[x] for x in headers_index]
    wr.writerow(output)
```

I assume that the headers are in the first row.

Comment: @EMp1 I added the part of the code in which I create the sh object. It works for me. How do you create it? that should work (Python 3)

Answer (score 1):

```
csv_file = open(csv_file_path, 'w+')
wr = csv.writer(csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

for row_num in xrange(sh.nrows):
  row = sh.row_values(row_num)
  wr.writerow([row[3], row[4]])
```

here 3 and 4 are index for columns Id and Price.

Answer (score 1):

Try that for exporting the 3rd and 4th column as an example

```
for row_num in xrange(sh.nrows): 
     wr.writerow([sh.cell(row_num, 2).value, sh.cell(row_num, 3).value])
```

reference : [Selecting multiple specific columns in excel and exporting to CSV using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38463349/selecting-multiple-specific-columns-in-excel-and-exporting-to-csv-using-python)